# How can I push my footer down to the very bottom of the page, regardless of how much or little content is in the body?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am dynamically generating the content of a web page's main content. The page also has a header and a footer. The header remains anchored to the top just fine, but the footer hugs the bottom of the body rather than anchoring to the bottom of the page. Even when the amount of dynamically generated content is nil or minimal, I want the footer to hug the bottom of the page. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post your code??

Comment: `bottom:0; position:fixed`?

Comment: Here's a good solution http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: ryanfait.com's solution is the best backward-compatible solution all around.

Comment: Ah - I think Frank Zappa had a song by that title ("Sticky Footer").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a sticky footer: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html

The following CSS is taken from the link above.

**CSS**

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html,
body {
     height: 100%;
     /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
     /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
     margin: 0 auto -60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#push,
#footer {
     height: 60px;
}
#footer {
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

/* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#footer {
     margin-left: -20px;
     margin-right: -20px;
     padding-left: 20px;
     padding-right: 20px;
}
}



/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

.container {
     width: auto;
     max-width: 680px;
}
.container .credit {
     margin: 20px 0;
}



/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

.container {
     width: auto;
     max-width: 680px;
}
.container .credit {
     margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to detect the height of the page + content AND the height of the window that has the website. If the height is less than the window, you would need to do position fixed, otherwise, let it sit normally and be pushed down by the content. This is the general approach. If you post code I can help show you how to make it work.